# Не отрабатывает событие на кнопке JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Всем привет. Помогите найти косяк. Нажатием на кнопку должна выполняться функция `editButton()`. Но вылетает в консоль с ошибкой

```
insertRow.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: editButton is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (insertRow.js:32)
(anonymous) @ insertRow.js:32
```

При этом полностью идентичный механизм `delButton()` отрабатывает нормально.

Что я делаю не так?

```js
function insertRow(id) {
  var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  var row;
  row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.setAttribute("id", "tr_id")
  var cellCounter = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;

  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellCounter));

  var td2 = document.createElement("td");
  var checkbox = document.createElement("input")
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkbox.setAttribute("id", "checkbox_id");
  td2.appendChild(checkbox);

  var td3 = document.createElement("td");
  td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("add_id").value));

  var td4 = document.createElement("td");
  td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("quant_id").value));

  var td5 = document.createElement("td");
  td5.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("price_id").value));

  var td6 = document.createElement("td");
  var editButton = document.createElement("input")
  editButton.setAttribute("class", "editButton")
  editButton.src = "icons/edit.png";
  editButton.type = "image";
  editButton.addEventListener('click', function() { // ВОТ ТУТ КОСЯК
    editButton('myTable');
    return false;
  });
  td6.appendChild(editButton);
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("input")
  deleteButton.setAttribute("class", "deleteButton")
  deleteButton.src = "icons/delete.png";
  deleteButton.type = "image";
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    delButton('myTable');
    return false;
  });
  td6.appendChild(deleteButton);

  td6.setAttribute("colspan", "2")

  row.appendChild(td1);
  row.appendChild(td2);
  row.appendChild(td3);
  row.appendChild(td4);
  row.appendChild(td5);
  row.appendChild(td6);
  tbody.appendChild(row);

  localStorage.setItem("add", document.getElementById("add_id").value);
  localStorage.setItem("quant", document.getElementById("quant_id").value);
  localStorage.setItem("price", document.getElementById("price_id").value);
}


function editButton(id) {
  localStorage.setItem("add_done", document.getElementById("add_id").value);
  localStorage.setItem("quant_done", document.getElementById("quant_id").value);
  localStorage.setItem("price_done", document.getElementById("price_id").value);
}

function delButton(id) {
  localStorage.setItem("add_del", document.getElementById("add_id").value);
  localStorage.setItem("quant_del", document.getElementById("quant_id").value);
  localStorage.setItem("price_del", document.getElementById("price_id").value);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тяжело придумывать новые названия для переменных? Сочувствую :).

Локальная переменная

```
var editButton = document.createElement("input")
```

захватывается в замыкание, и внутри обработчика `click` обращение идет именно к ней, а не к функции `editButton`. Назовите переменную по-другому, и все заработает:

```
var btnEdit = document.createElement("input");
btnEdit.setAttribute("class", "editButton");
btnEdit.src = "icons/edit.png";
btnEdit.type = "image";
btnEdit.addEventListener('click', function() { // ВОТ ТУТ БОЛьШЕ НЕТ КОСЯКA
  editButton('myTable');
  return false;
});

...

function editButton(id) {
  ...
```

Comment: Вот оно как в JS... Упустил этот момент. Впредь буду обращать внимание на это. Спасибо большое! )